# Converting IA32 Assembly to C code

Tags: c, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

I'm having some difficulty translating IA32 Assembly code back to its C code counterpart. I'm 99% of the way there, but the byte offsets and register storage are confusing me.

The assembly code in question, `movl %edx, %eax`, seems to set the value stored in `%eax` equal to the value in `%edx`, but wouldn't that mean `sub = result`?

I'm new to this, so your guidance is appreciated!

```
int d(int x, int y, int z)     // x at %ebp+8, y at %ebp+12, z at %ebp+16
{
    int sub, result;

    sub = z - y;               // movl 12(%ebp), %edx
    result = sub;              // subl 16(%ebp), %edx

    ???????????                // movl %edx, %eax

    result <<= 31;             // sall $31, %eax
    result >>= 31;             // sarl $31, %eax

    result = sub * result;     // imull 8(%ebp), %edx

    sub ^= x;                  // xorl %edx, %eax

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you have some typos in there. For example, `movl 12(%edx), %eax` is probably `movl 12(%ebp), %eax`. Also `eax` is `result` not `sub` (since `eax` is the return value). `subl 16(%ebp), %edx` makes no sense either, since `edx` has not been set.

Comment: I just compared it to my spec and made some fixes, however the `movl12` line is slightly different than what you suggested. Working on this now...

Edit: still unsure how to alter the C code in response to the IA32 change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two lines of asm are actually the first line of C but reversed and performed in two parts:

```
sub = y;                   // movl 12(%ebp), %edx
sub -= z;                  // subl 16(%ebp), %edx
```

You seem to have slight trouble with the fact that at&t syntax (that this is) puts the destination operand on the right. As such the `movl %edx, %eax` is indeed the `result = sub` as written in the code. Also, the `imull 8(%ebp), %edx` clearly writes into `edx` so that's `sub = x * result` (the `eax` operand is implicit). Finally `xorl %edx, %eax` is of course `result ^= sub`. `x`, which is `8(%ebp)`, is not even mentioned on that line.